# Installing new WD green hdd

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-mint

I've purchased a new Western Digital Green Power 1TB 3.5 inch internal hard drive on eBay but I can't get any of my desktops to recognise it.  Model number WD 10EURX.  I'm using Linux Mint 17 Mate and Windows 7.  The drive was made in 2014 but my motherboards are much older.  Even the BIOS upgrades are from earlier days. I've not had any luck searching for a driver or answers on the WD website.  I remember seeing something about problems with EURX or SEURX(?) internal green drives but I can't find the article again.  Can someone please suggest some first steps for me to take in order to progress with this problem (I'm suffering from a Brain Stall)?

Comment: Check to see if it shows up in the BIOS. If it doesn't, return it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to see you HDD in BIOS. If you saw them. The try to use program victorya HDD. This program can try "restore" lost sectors. And may be your got the working HDD. But unfortunately this hard disk drive is garbage - 99%.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is available in BIOS, you can try with [GParted](http://gparted.org/)

I think it is not included in the default mint installation, but for sure it is in the repos.

Once installed you can see in the top right corner if the drive is available. If it is available you can format it an then the OS should recognize it.

[image]

Another thing to check is the SATA cable - I've had a lot of cases when the cable or the port wont work.

Comment: Care to say why the downvote? Also SATA cables come with the motherboard, if he haven't bought new it is far more plausible to have faulty cable than HDD.

Comment: Poster did not do the down vote.

Comment: Sorry Pennywise, I don't understand the following: "I think it is not included in the default mint installation, but for sure it is in the repos."  What does "repos." mean and how do I get it?

Comment: The hdd came to me new, sealed and carefully packed, so I'm assuming it is good.  The problem is not a SATA port or cable, as I've tried various computers and cables.  It's just that the BIOS does not recognize it (even after updating) and I don't have a driver for the operating system, neither Mint or Windows.  I'm sure such things exist. I don't like the websites that say "give me money and I'll checkout all your drivers", not the way I like to work.